# Read from file; and execute its content line by line; terminate at first error

Tags: bash, echo, read

I am reading the content of a file `do.sh` using the bash command line structure. I want to execute each line of this file, line by line, so that, later, I can add some text to the script which can handle the failure of any of the in-between lines and stop the execution of afterwards content. The syntax I am using for this is

```bash
cat do.sh|while read lin;do (echo $(" $lin")) ;done
echo $amit
```

Assuming the content of do.sh is

```
amit=3
ram=/path/to/some/dir
ls >> amit.log
```

In the end, I should be able to access the content of the two variables (i.e `amit`, `ram`), and the output of `ls` command should be stored in `amit.log`
I am not able to figure out the mistake.

Comment: I have some thoughts about this, but why don't you want to use `source`?

Comment: This question isn’t asking for a way to terminate the sourcing of the script as soon as there is an error; it’s laying the groundwork for a forthcoming activity that does that.   Based on that (negative) understanding, and given the answers that the OP has rejected, I do not understand what this question *is* asking.

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' : I want a syntex like `while IFS= read line;do (  eval $line; if [ $? -ne 0 ];then exit;fi);done< do.sh` to solve the prob.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sourcing the dot-script using either the standard

```bash
. ./do.sh
```

or non-standard

```bash
source ./do.sh
```

... would have solved the original question, which only asked about a way of executing the script and leaving the created variables in the current environment (and creating the file containing the output of `ls`).

The updated question additionally asks for a way to terminate the sourcing of the script as soon as there is an error.  I'm going to assume "error" means that some command exits with a non-zero exit status.

Usually, one could run a script with `set -e` enabled to let it terminate at the first error, but since this script must be *sourced*, we can't do that (it would terminate the current shell).  Instead, we may use a feature in `bash` that allows us to execute an arbitrary command as soon as a command terminates with a non-zero exit status.  The command we want to execute is `return` as soon as there is an error.  This will stop the execution of the script and return the exit status in `$?` in the current shell.

Therefore:

```bash
trap 'err=$?; trap - ERR; return "$err"' ERR
. ./do.sh
trap - ERR
```

This sets the `ERR` trap to the command `err=$?; trap - ERR; return "$err"`.  This command will be executed upon any error, saving the exit status in `err`, unsetting the trap, and returning the error to the shell in `$?` (it also leaves the exit status in the variable `err`).  The final `trap - ERR` resets the `ERR` trap to the default.

Example:

Our script is modified to include a call to `false`, which we use to simulate a command that fails.  We expect the variables to be set but for the file `amit.log` to not be created.

```bash
$ cat do.sh
amit=3
ram=/path/to/some/dir
false
ls >> amit.log
```

Run our commands:

```
$ trap 'err=$?;trap - ERR;return "$err"' ERR
$ . ./do.sh
$ trap - ERR
```

Show that we got the variables but that the file wasn't created:

```bash
$ printf '%s\n' "$amit" "$ram"
3
/path/to/some/dir
$ ls
do.sh
```

Comment: Yes this solves the problem.

Comment: But I am more interested solving problem along the line of 
`while IFS= read line;do (  eval $line; if [ $? -ne 0 ];then exit;fi);done< do.sh
`

Comment: Your method will terminate the process on the first error occurrence. But along the line, I am interested, I will also get at which line process terminated. (As per my little understanding)

Answer (score 3):

Several issues:

- You are executing the commands in a subshell. Changes in a subshell environment aren't propagated to the parent shell.
- You aren't assigning anything. 
  Assignments happen before variable expansion, so when `" $lin"` is expanded,
  it's understood as a command by the enclosing `$(...)`, not as an assignment. 
  In other words, it tries to execute a command called `amit=3`,
  as if you had typed `"amit=3"` (*with* the quotation marks).
  P.S. Leaving out the quotes in `do (echo $(" $lin"))` won't help that;
  please don't even think about trying that.
- You are running the whole thing in a pipeline. Without `lastpipe`, this will again run in a subshell, i.e. the changes won't be propagated to the parent shell.

This fixes all the issues:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s lastpipe
cat do.sh | while read lin ; do
    eval "$lin"
done

echo "$amit $ram"
```

But, it introduces issues: what if someone changes the file to contain `rm -rf *`?

Comment: @ Choroba: When I ececute the equivalent code using a shell script, it works. But when I run the same lines of code directly on the terminal, it doesn't. Could you please add to this also? (I don't know the behavior of 'shopt -s lastpipe' as I am a newbie to this language)

Comment: By equivalent code I mean 
```shell
shopt -s lastpipe;cat do.sh | while read lin ; do eval "$lin"; done;echo "$amit"
```

Comment: `lastpipe` only works where job control is not active (see https://stackoverflow.com/q/44864746/1030675)

Comment: There are still more issues like the UUOC (without which you wouldn't need lastpipe), missing -r and IFS= to `read`, missing `--` for `eval`, using `echo`

Comment: This will likely work only on a file containing single-line commands (and commands on multiple lines if the newline characters are escaped).  Any compound command stretching more than a single line is unfortunately bound to fail.

Comment: Is it a problem if someone changes the file to contain `rm -rf *`? Wouldn't the script execute it just fine?

Comment: @ilkkachu: It might be a problem if the user who modifies the input doesn't have the permission to run the program, and it runs as a different user.

Answer (score 3):

If all you want to do is import the variables from do.sh then this should do it.

```
#!/bin/bash

. ./do.sh

echo "$amit $ram"
```

The `.` before the `./do.sh` tells the interpreter to execute the file in the current environment so any variables set in do.sh can be accessed.

Comment: The dot at the start of the line is shorthand for the 'source' directive.

Comment: @symcbean Believe it or not, but the source command is another name for the dot command, not the other way around.

Answer (score 2):

```
[root@x ~]# cat /tmp/sk221
amit=3
ram=/tmp/sk12

[root@x ~]# . /tmp/sk221

[root@x ~]# echo $amit
3

[root@x ~]# echo $ram
/tmp/sk12
```

Comment: This is not what I am looking for.

Comment: @Amit, why not? It's the best way to evaluate sh code in the current shell.

Comment: @Jack: The question is more inclined to the line-by-line reading and execution of the content red from another file, rather than some variable storage way out

Comment: @AmitKr.Ratewal Is the end goal to have two variables? If so, this is a solution to that problem. If it does not answer your question, you'd best update the question with a motivation to why sourcing the file is not appropriate.

Comment: Thanks Kusal, I have already added the relevant text. Please mind the text related to the output of 'ls' command.

Comment: @AmitKr.Ratewal Sourcing the file would execute the `ls` command and create the file. You have added nothing to the question that makes this answer invalid.

Comment: Thaks Kusal & Jack, I agree sourcing do solve the original question asked. However the intention of the question was not that sourcing could solve. Hence I have tried to update the question.